# Trying to simplify the steps for Conditional Compilation in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, conditional-compilation

**Background:**

What i'm trying to do is to customize the build procedure for my project in the VS2008 IDE based on the set of configuration i need at a given point of time.

My project has some conditional methods e.g.**[Conditional("FULLFEATURE")]** or [Conditional("LESSFEATURE")] which execute only when i mention the FULLFEATURE or LESSFEATURE conditional compilation symbol in the Build project properties.

This approach is laborious as each time when i have to compile through the (VSNET IDE) i have to manually add a compilation symbol depending on my requirement.

**Question**

Is there a way where in i can avoid this ( maintain two different copies of project for each feature, No i don't want this approach) ?

Is there a way through the configuration manager wherein i can just select one amongst

```
FULLFEATURE --> Debug ---> x86
FULLFEATURE --> Debug ---> AnyCPU
FULLFEATURE --> Release ---> x86
FULLFEATURE --> Release ---> AnyCPU


LESSFEATURE --> Debug ---> x86
LESSFEATURE--> Debug ---> AnyCPU
LESSFEATURE--> Release ---> x86
LESSFEATURE--> Release ---> AnyCPU
```

to build in whatever configuration i need. 
I know this approach is going to get nasty if i have more number of conditional compilation symbols. But here i am ..

Any suggestions most welcome

Cheers

Comment: Why is not possible to use the configuration manager to create the four separate build configurations?

Comment: I've done this before with a `MSBUILD` script that sets the condition, compiles, changes the condition, compiles to a different output dir.

Comment: @Boo : I know we can do this using MSBUILD, thats the reason i specifically mentioned VS2008 IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build + Configuration Manager.  Use the upper left combobox labelled "Active solution configuration" and select `New...`.  Type a new name.  Project + Properties, Build tab and set your conditional.  Each configuration will now have its own conditionals.

You now simply switch between configurations with the configuration selector on the toolbar and build/debug as needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Although i tried this, i thought changing the Build configuration would override the old config. so dumb of me.!!